# Unable to use Python 3.5 on Windows from Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to run python 3 in a Windows 10 machine.
I already installed python 3 and changed the path variable:

```
C:\Users\felipe.ferminiano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\;C:\Users\felipe.ferminiano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\
```

but when I run python3 I get:

```
python3 is not recognized as an internal command
```

whe I run python I get:

```
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It seems you have installed Anaconda in python 2.7 so create an env with python=3 and just fire python in the env

Answer (score 1):

Without a `python3.exe` file, it will fail.

Use `py` instead to specify the exact version `py -2 or py -3`

Comment: I changed my PATH var to: C:\Users\felipe.ferminiano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\;C:\Users\felipe.ferminiano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe but it still doesn't work